# why use xcode if monotouch is available?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

if mono touch is available than why we should use mac environment(sdk,xcode+Interface Builder)?

what are the disadvantage of monotouch compare to xcode?

Comment: use monotouch if you want to develop using c#, use xcode if your want to use objective-c

Comment: Because you don't know C#. Because you like Objective-C. Because you have a Mac environment. Because *you want to*. What's wrong with choice?

Comment: i have my thesis presentation, so may be the question will arise that monotouch is available then why you choose Mac environment.

Comment: Also, even with monotouch you still need a Mac environment

Comment: For signing packages, you still need xcode and so Mac

Comment: @Adeel, you should post that as an answer. That's as concrete and objective an answer as he's likely to get to this question.

Comment: @Adeel, @Dan Ray, you don't really need to use XCode to sign the app. You can just add the Apple certificate to the KeyChain, and build using MonoDevelop / MonoTouch.

Comment: How about that monotouch is another $$ expense after having to shell out $ just to be an apple developer

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I always prefer working in the language that is most philosophically aligned with the platform I am developing for.

That is to say, the frameworks the whole platform is built around were written for and in Objective-C.  As such, if you are working in Objective-C yourself for a while you understand why things are built the way they are, and can also anticipate calls that might exist or behaviors.

Just as I would not develop for Windows Phone 7 in anything but Silverlight, I would not program the iPhone in anything but Objective-C in order to get the most out of the platform.  New language?  That's a benefit as people should learn new languages now and then anyway.  And it's not like it saves you that much time to use a language you already know since a large majority of your time will be spent learning the frameworks (which MonoTouch lets you call into).

Comment: sorry, but I disagree. while it makes sense to work in the best ideologically suitable language, I believe Objective C's characteristics make the case a lot less compelling. or, put it another way, C# is just too powerful a language to pass by the opportunity.

Comment: If you use modern objective-C C# does not seem more powerful.  Lacking ARC and a syntax to directly work with collection objects (which you need for a lot of API calls) is a big drawback as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Two words: "LINQ" and "Lambdas". /End.

Comment: Two words: NSPredicate and Blocks.  /End.  Know your languages before you critique.  And a final word: ARC.

Comment: The syntax for LINQ and Lambdas is much cleaner. FYI I've just started using Objective-C, but I think anyone can agree that the syntax isn't all that great. Other than that though I think it's great.

Comment: I disagree;  I think the syntax for Objective-C is fine.  You use used to the verbosity.  The important point is that functionality exists if you need it, also of note is that block use is now wide-spread through the standard frameworks so it's not just something to make your own code better.

Answer (score 10):

I feel like this needs an answer from the MT camp, too.

Why eat fish, if you can have meat? Why speak German, if English is understood? Why watch CNN if there is FOX? Why vote vote for the Republicans if there are the Democrats? Why...? And so on.

It is your choice! If you have worked with C# for a long time and want to have quick results on iOS, go MonoTouch. Especially if you have a collection of APIs or methods you can reuse, MT is the way to go. If you want to learn a new language (ObjC), go for it. Even if you use MT in the end, knowing ObjC is somehow crucial because it helps you understand why things work as they do.

Comment: Please avoid adding taglines and signatures to posts.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038/171789 for more information on the StackExchange policy.

Answer (score 9):

Hello here is my personal opinion,

I've also been on .Net world for a while, when iPhone launched the ability to create native apps, it called my whole attention and i really tried to learn objc, i took 2 books and started trying and trying and trying like for a month and then I left iPHone programming due to you had to make tons of things than on .NET was a line away for example the GC.

When Miguel de Icaza launched MonoTouch i gave it a try and i realized that most of my previously done code was fully funcional (i've always tried to separate ui code from business code) and this is really the point of .NET on the iPhone, to bring most of your already done business logic to the device.

Also on objc you wont find anything like LINQ or var keyword, consuming web services on MonoTouch its just a few clicks away etc.

If you want to target the Android platform there is also MonoDroid (monodroid.net) wich its coming out later this year the stable release, you can give it a try right now on the beta state. Also if you want to target Mac OSX there is MonoMac. So you can share class libs between all this 3 platforms (also al mono/.net supported ones) without hassle not to mention it will work on windows too and viceversa (when possible) (Also dont forget about WP7).

The only thing you will need to worry about its the UI but most of your business logic should work. here is a complete list of .NET Assemblies supported in MonoTouch http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Assemblies and also MonoTouch exposes a C#/CIL binding to all the CocoaTouch APIs.

Also the support of the MonoTouch team is awesome you can just get on IRC ans ask a question and it will be answered right away, mailing list too :)

I really enjoy MonoTouch, i know that no language is perfect for all tasks, and Objective-C is no exception.

Answer (score 2):

Every example, tutorial, and piece of documentation will be written in Objective-C, and mono will just be calling into Objective-C code under the hood. If you really feel like C# is worth mentally translating everything, and adding an extra layer in your code, go for it I guess.

Comment: MonoTouch is not merely a binding to the underlying Objective-C platform. It extends the .NET type system and dispatch system to better blend C# and Objective-C.

Just like P/Invoke is a useful tool to invoke native libraries on Windows and Linux, or how IJW support can be used for COM interop on Windows, MonoTouch extends the runtime to support binding C# objects to Objective-C objects.

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/API_Design

Comment: Sure, but you're still going to have to use the underlying platform APIs, which are ObjC.

Answer (score 0):

As a C# developer, I've found Objective-C to be horribly painful to become confident with.  It's taken about two months, and two excellent resources to get to this stage.

Get your Visa card out, you'll need to spend a total of $54.

**1.  The *free* Stanford "Developing apps for iOS" lectures.**
Pure brilliance, and it makes learning Objective-C very clear.
http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-sd/id395631522

**2.  The iOS Apprentice series.**
This is where you'll need to cough up the $54.  It teaches you, step by step, how to program in Objective-C, and the apps you build are actually pretty impressive.  Part 1 (of the 4 parts) is completely free, so you can give it a go before parting with any cash.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-apprentice

I've yet to find any iOS books which match the clarity and friendliness of these two resources.

Finally, *don't* buy any books unless they specifically say that they're for iOS5 and XCode 4.  This latest version of XCode is simply too different to make them useful.

*Disclaimer: I don't work for any of the resources mentioned in this thread !*